# Does docker contain trackers/analytics

Tags: docker, analytics

I am currently working through the zero to production in rust book. This is based around cloud native web apps in rust and therefore uses a postgresql database within a docker image. I run linux with purely foss/tracker-free software on my main OS with anything that contains trackers/analytics confined to virtual boxes.

As I will need to install docker for the book I am trying to work out if it contains trackers, to work out if it can go on my main OS or if I need to box it, from what I can tell parts of docker are open source whereas others are not and I can't find if any analytics are bundled with it (like in VS code). Does anyone know where I can find info on this and/or if there are any good FOSS alternatives to docker.

P.S.
There is a similar question here from 2017 https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/5436/is-docker-still-free-and-open-source however as the answers are from over 7 years ago it isn't clear if this is still accurate